# Race condition using a code segment

Tags: operating-system

Please help me to get an idea to solve this question.I have tried several sequence to race condition, but i couldn't get a correct one.
every time the value of x is same.

[image]

This is the way I've tried

[image]

Comment: make an effort first. What do YOU think is happening currently?

Comment: I've uploaded the way i've tried, currently the x s value is same even the execution sequence is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that a line isn't to be considered an atomic operation, you can split up any of the lines modifying x based on its own value into a *read* and *write* part. Doing this only for one, for example from the `increase` function, yields:

```
y = 5;
int temporary = x; // read value
temporary += y;
x = temporary; // write modified value back
x++; // this could be split up similarly
z = /* whatever */;
```

With this "expanded" code sequence you should have no problem finding sequences of operations with different result values for `x`.